# select and set multiple vars sql2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I set multiple values before an insert statement? The below doesnt work.

```
declare @foo int
declare @bar int
set (select @foo=foo, @bar=bar from Foobar where id=123);

insert into ...
select @foo, 3, @bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
declare @foo int
declare @bar int
select @foo=foo, @bar=bar from Foobar where id=123;

insert into ...
select @foo, 3, @bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the variables by using `SELECT`:

```
select @foo=foo, @bar=bar from Foobar where id=123;
```

Or, just skip the variables and combine the [`SELECT` and `INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
insert into ...
select foo, bar
from Foobar
where id = 123;
```